# Call function from other class odoo 9

Tags: odoo, odoo-9

In a custom module I have two classes. How can class `test` in `@api.one` call `test2_func` on a button click?

What should I put in `def call_test2_func(self)`?

For example:

```
class test(models.Model):
    _name = "test.class"
    _description = "TEST"
@api.one
    def call_test2_func(self):
  """call test2_func here"""

class test2(models.Model):
    _name = "test2.class"
    _description = "TEST 2"

@api.one
    def test2_func(self):
        print("TEST 2")
```

Comment: To call a function from another model you can use `self.env["model_name"].myfunction`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Maybe I should leave a reply instead of a comment. If you're using Odoo and the new OpenERP api you can can access the model dictionaty though `self.env` in your model classes. So to call the function `test2_func` in the model `test2.class` you should write

```
@api.one
def call_test2_func(self):
    self.env["test2.class"].test2_func()
```